# Find texts from one sheet and use it to replace in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

There are 2 sheets in my excel file (Sheet 1 and 2).

In Sheet 1, there are 3 columns - Code, ID and text. There are more than 100 records here.

In Sheet 2, there is heaps of data.

I am trying to write VBA that:

1) finds 'code' (Sheet1) from the second column of Sheet2;

2) finds 'ID' (Sheet1) from the third row of Sheet2 and get the column number;

3) Paste 'text' (Sheet1) in the respective row and column in Sheet2.

I have written down the below code but it is not pasting 'text' in the respective column - rather pastes in all the columns matching the 'IDs'

Please assist. Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rngCell_1 As Range
Dim rngCell_2 As Range
Dim rngCell_3 As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sht = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

With sht2

lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowcell = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Row = 4 To lastrow
    For Each rngCell_2 In sht.Range("B2:B" & lastrowcell)
    Set rng1 = sht2.UsedRange.Find(rngCell_2, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        For Each rngCell_1 In sht.Range("A2:A" & lastrowcell)
            For Each rngCell_3 In sht.Range("C2:C" & lastrowcell)
                If (.Cells(Row, 2) = rngCell_1) Then
                    .Cells(Row, rng1.Column) = rngCell_3
                    .Cells(Row, rng1.Column).Font.Color = 255
                    End If
            Next rngCell_3
        Next rngCell_1
    Next rngCell_2
Next Row
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer `Find()` here in place of nested loops:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range, f1 As Range, f2 As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set rw = sht1.Range("A2:C2")

    Do While Application.CountA(rw) = 3

        Set f1 = sht2.Columns(2).Find(rw.Cells(1), lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not f1 Is Nothing Then

            Set f2 = sht2.Rows(2).Find(rw.Cells(2), lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not f2 Is Nothing Then
                sht2.Cells(f1.Row, f2.Column).Value = rw.Cells(3).Value
            End If

        End If

        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```